# How to export embedded documents from Mongo DB to excel sheet in java

Tags: java, excel, mongodb

Schema in MongoDB:

{
"Name" : "Kamala", 
"Flows" : [
 {
    "Date" : "2018-08-03",
    "New" : "set",
     "Form" : {
      "y" : "1",
      "d" : "3"
      "p" : "3"
        }
    }
]
}

In java

```
String db = "Database";
 String col = "col";
 String Host="localhost";
 String Port="27017";
 String fileName = "D:/File/sample.xls";

 String Query = "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.4\\bin\\mongoexport.exe --host " + Host + " --port " + Port + " --db " + db + " --collection " + col + " --type=xls--fields Name,Flows, --out " + fileName + "";

 try {
     System.out.println(Query);

     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Query);
     String[] Queryarray = new String[st.countTokens()];
     for (int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
         Queryarray[i] = st.nextToken();

     ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Queryarray);
     processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

     Process process = processBuilder.start();
     BufferedReader processOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

     String data = "";
     while ((data = processOutput.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(data);
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}

I tried this code but whole document store in one cell(in excel) but, I'm trying to store this document in this type ( name ,Date ,New,Form)